# Error compilación Template Typename c++

Tags: c++, template, struct

Estoy intentando implementar un retículo y para ello uso templates, pero obtengo el error de abajo que no se a que se debe, esta es la clase Lattice.hpp:

```
template < typename N >

class Lattice{
        private:
                int count;
                bool was_inserted;
                int last_position_index;

                struct Node{

                        int index;
                        N c;
                        pair<vector<int>,vector<int>> upperLowerNeighbots;

                        Node(){};

                        Node(const N& con,int i){
                                c=con;
                                index=i;
                        }

                        bool operator==(const Node& n) const{
                                return c.first == n.c.first; 
                        }
                };

                list<Node> concepts; 
        public:
                Lattice();
                /**
                 * @brief Retrieves the list of concepts of the lattice.
                 * @return The list of concepts of the lattice.
                 */
                
                list<N> getConcepts();

                /**
                 * @brief Adds a new formal concept to the lattice.
                 * @param concept The formal concept to be added.
                 */
                
                void add(N concept);

                bool find(N& concp);

                bool next(N& c, N& output);
                
                bool insertLookUp(N& x, N& c);


};
```

en Lattice.cpp , defino las funciones todas igual, muestro solo la que da error, que es el constructor sin parámetros Lattice.cpp:

```
#include "Lattice.hpp"

template<typename N>
Lattice<N>::Lattice(){
    count=0;
    last_position_index=0;
    was_inserted=false;
}
```

Por último , en el main.cpp:

```
#include "Lattice.hpp"
#include "Algorithms.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  Context c;
  list<formalConcept> test;
  Lattice<formalConcept> l;

  return 0;
```

***referencia a `Lattice<std::pair<std::vector<int, std::allocator >, std::vector<int, std::allocator > > >::Lattice()' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status***

Comment: Todo lo que tenga que ver con templates tiene que estar en el header. Mueve el constructor al `.hpp` y veras como se soluciona el error.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he solucionado el error en el main con el constructor metiendolo en el lattice.hpp, pero el resto de funciones de la clase Lattice siguen dando error , como si no estuvieran definidas...